# How to return dynamic values of inputs?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that renders a form that has 2 date inputs, I want to get the date input values inside another function, that triggers on click. The values I return are not dynamic, I change them, and when I click submit I still get the old values.

This is what I've tried:

```
function renderInvoice() {
      let invoiceForm = document.querySelector('.invoice');
      invoiceForm.innerHTML = `
        <h1>Facturi de intrare</h1>
        <label for="start">Start date:</label>
        <input class="date-input" type="date" id="start" name="start" value="2020-06-02" min="2000-01-01" max="2030-01-01">
        <label for="end">End date:</label>
        <input class="date-input" type="date" id="end" name="end" value="2020-06-02" min="2000-01-01" max="2030-01-01">
        <button id="invoiceBtn" type="button">Submit</button>
        `;
      invoiceForm.addEventListener('submit',function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       getReceivedInvoice();
     })
    }
```

The function where I get the returned values:

```
async function getReceivedInvoice() {
      // Need to get input[type=date] values here
      const url = 'http://example.com/param?';
      const params = { DateStart: /* date input goes here */, DateEnd: /* date input goes here */ };
      url.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
    }
```

Comment: What is `getReceivedInvoice`?

Comment: Your function `renderInvoice` only renders the DOM elements. It does not wait for the user to input anything and hit the submit button. You're taking the input values immediately after rendering, when they are still empty.

Comment: @Bergi, a POST Request function, I need the date input values to send them to the server.

Comment: @Bergi, how do I handle this?

Comment: Put the stuff that access the start and end input values inside the `getReceivedInvoice`. Don't try to `return` anything from the `render` function.

Comment: @Bergi, how do I do that exactly?

Comment: @Bergi, anything outside renderInvoice() is not defined :( when I try to access

Comment: I can't tell unless you post the code of the `getReceivedInvoice` function that is installed as the click listener and does the post request. Oh wait, is that the function from your second snippet? And it calls `renderInvoice` again? That makes no sense.

Comment: @Bergi, check it out again, I fixed the code.

Comment: Just call `getReceivedInvoice(invoiceForm.start.value, invoiceForm.end.value)` in that event listener, and declare `async function getReceivedInvoice(start, end) { … }`

Comment: @Bergi, It worked, thanks!